# Camel: How to increment the value of an Integer header by a set amount

Tags: apache-camel

Here is my code so far, where I would like to increment the value of the `offset` header by `50`:

```
.process(new Processor() {
     @Override
     public void process(Exchange ex){  
         ex.getIn().setHeader("offset", Integer.parseInt(ex.getIn().getHeader("offset").toString())); }
  })
```

Anybody know of a simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are increasing your integer header by `50` in your code [NOTE: Question was edited afterwards]. You just seem to be parsing a `String` into an Integer. You can simplify it by leveraging **type conversions**:

```
Message in = ex.getIn();
in.setHeader("offset", in.getHeader("offset", Integer.class));
```

If you want to increment the offset header by `50`, you can do it **inside your route** with the help of [**OGNL**](https://camel.apache.org/ognl.html) (no need to resort to a Processor, like the other answer suggested), and by converting the header first to an Integer:

```
from("direct:hello")
    .setHeader("offset", header("offset").convertTo(Integer.class))
    .setHeader("offset").ognl("request.headers.offset + 50");
```

Comment: one more dependency for just a simple incremental operation... :( sad.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the built in [**Simple language**](https://camel.apache.org/simple.html) doesn't support arithmetic operations. Sorry! By the way, I chose OGNL because it's the most lightweight language option, but if you're using Groovy, Javascript, SpEL, MVEL, etc. in your other routes, you can probably rewrite the expression to reuse that other library.

Comment: Nice solution, if there are no problems with installing additional features on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I am using such processor for this:

```
public class IncrementIntProcessor implements Processor {
    private String headerName;
    private int delta = 1;

    public IncrementIntProcessor(String headerName){
        this.headerName = headerName;
    }

    public IncrementIntProcessor(String headerName, int delta){
        this.headerName = headerName;
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        int num = (exchange.getIn().getHeader(headerName)==null ? 0 : exchange.getIn().getHeader(headerName, Integer.class));
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(headerName, (num+delta));
    }
}
```

Example:

```
            ....
            .process(new IncrementIntProcessor("intHeader", 50))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${header.intHeader}")
            ....
```

Interesting to see other, simple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

However, for much more complex use cases you are generally recommended to choose a more expressive and powerful language such as SpEL, Groovy, OGNL and [others](https://camel.apache.org/simple.html).

If you use Spring, you may already be using SpEL.

I rewrote the expression using SpEL:

```
from("direct:hello")
  .setHeader("offset").spel("#{request.headers['offset'] != null ? request.headers['offset'] + 1 : 1}")
```